# simple counter to track form ussage?

Tags: vb.net, addition, counter

I would like to know how I can read a number from a text file then multiply that figure by one and write that back to the original text file, I'm trying to make a counter to keep track of how many times my forms are executed. The information will then be used to determine the success of my apps with in our company.

Comment: you don't need any code for that. multiplying by one does not change the value of anything. besides your question is too vague. what are you having trouble with exactly? reading a file? writing one? those topics are covered by tutorials and documentation easily accessible through a web search.

Comment: Side note: if you really want a multiplication by one, you should replace the `+` in my example with a `*` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Private Sub Increment()
    Dim Path_To_File As String = "Path to the file"
    Try
        Dim Counter As Integer = CInt(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path_To_File))
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path_To_File, (Counter + 1).ToString(), False)
    Catch Ex As Exception ' Modifiy to catch specific errors if you want
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " & Ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```